# Using XPath to select an element with id that also contains text

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to select a `button` with `id` of `"some-id"` that also contains this text: `"some-text"`, however, this selector isn't working am I'm not sure why:

```
//button[contains(@id, "some-id") and contains(., "some-text")]
```

What's the proper selector to do this?

Here's a DOM example:

```
<main>
  <button id="some-id">
    <svg>...</svg>
    <i />
    some-text
  </button>
</main>
```

The selector returns no elements and I'm not sure why. Could it be related to new lines within the `<button />` element?

This selector does select the element:

```
//button[contains(@id, "some-id")]
```

Comment: I suspect that the issue has been lost in your simplification.  As posted, that XPath would select the `button` element.  Here are some things that could go wrong with your actual problem:  (a) You might be executing the XPath before the expected DOM has loaded or has been dynamically written.  (b) `some-text` may actually be within the `svg` element, which would require that your XPath be adjusted to account for the namespace of the `svg` element.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful to know. I suspected I had an invalid selector, but it seems that's not the case. I'll post updates if I find the issue

Comment: For (a), you might see if your targeted element is among those returned by `//*`.  For (b), see if `//button[contains(@id, "some-id")]` alone selects your targeted element.  BTW, if you don't need/want a substring test, use `//button[@id="some-id")]` instead.

Comment: Ah shoot, the issue was that I was selecting the text `"Support"` but the DOM instead had the text `"support"` and was capitalized with CSS

Comment: Ah, that'll do it!   Congrats on finding it.